# How do I Insert Image in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I am trying to insert an image in my markdown file but it's not rendering.

`![Image]{./Resource/img/Profile.jpeg}`

I tried using the absolute path also but that didn't worked either.

`![Image]{E:\Tutorials\Markdown\Resource\img\Profile.jpeg}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax used here is wrong. The link is supposed to be wrapped inside a
`()` bracket, rather thn `{}`.